# How to transform ordinal values into categorical ones?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-analysis, categorical-data

In a Pandas `DataFrame`, how can a column that represents a categorical feature (e.g. whether the day is a working day or a weekend) in an ordinal numerical form (say, 1 for working day, 2 for weekend) be transformed so that it represents the values in an categorical way, something like (0, 1) for working days and (1, 0) for weekends, so that the values are not comparable?

There is the alternative of using `pd.get_dummies` (or the `OneHotEncoder`), which would create two columns with 0s and 1s, and then merge the two columns in tuples, but is there not direct way of doing that?

Example:
I have:

```
    datetime    temp    daytype
0   2011-01-01  9.84    2
1   2011-01-02  9.02    2
2   2011-01-03  9.02    1
3   2011-01-04  9.84    1
4   2011-01-05  9.84    1
5   2011-01-06  9.84    1
```

I would like:

```
    datetime    temp    daytype
0   2011-01-01  9.84    (1, 0)
1   2011-01-02  9.02    (1, 0)
2   2011-01-03  9.02    (0, 1)
3   2011-01-04  9.84    (0, 1)
4   2011-01-05  9.84    (0, 1)
5   2011-01-06  9.84    (0, 1)
```

(I'm starting to think that maybe I'm getting it wrong - is this not the default way of representing categorical values?)

Comment: Did you see the [documentation on categorical data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html)?

Comment: I think you need `df['daytype'] = df['daytype'].astype('category')`

Comment: Yes, the astype or dtype are also recommended from the documentation. I believe I was (wrongly) searching for a way to actually visualize that the values are not comparable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your dummies/one hot vector and then combine them into a tuple:

Your original data looks something like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"daytype": [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2]})
print(df)

   daytype
0        2
1        2
2        1
3        1
4        1
5        2
```

We can create dummy variables, which as you correctly pointed out, will result in separate columns:

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df["daytype"]).astype(int)
print(dummies)

   1  2
0  0  1
1  0  1
2  1  0
3  1  0
4  1  0
5  0  1
```

But then you can take those separate columns and zip them together and assign the result back as a column in your original:

```
df["combined"] = list(zip(dummies[1], dummies[2]))
```

Giving you:

```
print(df)

   daytype combined
0        2   (0, 1)
1        2   (0, 1)
2        1   (1, 0)
3        1   (1, 0)
4        1   (1, 0)
5        2   (0, 1)
```

Of course you can entirely replace the original column with the combined if you want, I just separated them for clarity

The above will give you the desired results you posted in the original question, however you can also directly set the type of that specific column as mentioned in the comments:

```
df['daytype'] = df['daytype'].astype('category')
```

Ultimately it will come down to what you want to use the column to do

Comment: Yep, the get_dummies + merge would give me what I wanted, but I was wondering whether there is some encoder that does that directly :D. Thank you.

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think theres a builtin that will directly give you that as I cant think of a situation where representing a category that way would be useful. What are you planning on doing with the new combined column?

Comment: I was planning on running linear regression on the transformed data frame.

Comment: I'm not sure how you were planning on feeding a tuple `(0,1)` as a predictor to regression. When you do linear regression with categorical data the dummy variable approach is correct i.e. you have separate columns to represent the contrast between each category and a reference category

Comment: Also, if you store the tuple in a dataframe column, when you want to use it for regression later you would need to split the tuple into individual elements anyway. so if you have to split it up eventually anyway it doesnt make much sense to store it that way in the first place

Comment: Great, thank you, Simon, this information was what I was missing. I thought that was the default way of representing categories: different, incomparable values in one column, so I was expecting some encoder to provide it. Will use the multiple columns.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to do it : `df['daytype'] = df['daytype'].apply(lambda x : (1, 0) if x == 2 else (0,1))`